# how to access local MySQL from remote web page(PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, local, remote-access

My data in my local **MySql (Wamp sever)** I need to access this database from a webpage(php) from i hosted in remotely like www.11j.com/show.php. please describe clearly.

Comment: For security reasons, this is an EXTREMELY bad idea.  Generally, you should only be accessing your database on the same server that it resides on.  For this reason, what you're asking for may not even be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to a MySQL server, there are typically four variables you need to set:

- Database name
- Database user
- Password
- Host

When connecting to a MySQL server on the same host, the "host" variable is "localhost". When it's on a remote server, you set it to the IP address of the remote MySQL server.

However, there are a couple of other things you need to set up:

- Remote MySQL access must be enabled on the remote server
- The port MySQL runs on must be opened, not blocked by a firewall (by default, MySQL runs on port 3306)
- The username you are connecting with must have access to log on as a remote user

Remote access is not in itself an extremely bad idea and there are many scenarios when it's justified. However, in order to keep it as secure as possible:

- Remote MySQL users should only have access to the databases they need remote access to
- If possible, they should be restricted to logging on only from specific IP addresses

Answer (score -1):

To do that you should static IP for your server then you set the server with this static IP when you connect to mysql database.